# Prevent Back button after logout in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am tring to prevent back button after logout. So I wrote set_no_cache method in application.rb file. But it is not able to prevent back button functionality.

```
appliction_controller.rb :
 before_filter :set_cache_buster

 def set_cache_buster
   response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,   must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

I commented the 'turbolinks' gem and removed following line from application.js :
//= require turbolinks

I am using rails 4.1.6

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: put the `before_filter` in `application_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried out this but still it didn't worked.

Comment: If you are using devise, also add `:authenticate_user!` in the before action of your controllers( not for all of them, only the ones you want to be authenticated).

Comment: try redirecting to a page if 'no-cache' is there.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you don't want logged out users to see protected resources, I think there's something wrong with how you protect them - not the cache.